# Using * with string pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I'm pretty new to C and I got stuck with pointers.

My question is this: when do I use the * when accessing string pointer, and when don't I use it?

I understood that when I want to access the variable the pointer points to address I don't use the *, but when I want to access the variable's value I do add the *.
But the code below

```
char str1[] = "Hello", str2[] = "World";
char * ptr1, * ptr2;
ptr1 = &str1; ptr2 = &str2;
printf("%s %s\n", str1, str2);
printf("%s %s\n", ptr1, ptr2);    
printf("%s %s\n", *ptr1, *ptr2);
```

produces the following output:

```
Hello World

Hello World

Segmentation Fault
```

I get a 139 exit code when executing this program.
So it seems as if the * doesn't work here. I'll be very happy for any help regarding this.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Do you get any warnings when you compile?

Comment: I use the GDB compiler, and I don't get any warnings. I do get a 139 exit code though.

Comment: `ptr1 = &str1; ptr2 = &str2;` is bad code: mis-match pointer types.  A good compiler with warnings enabled would say why.  I am not sure what you are typing to do.

Comment: GDB is noit a compiler, but a debugger. Sorry, to tell, but your question is full of wrong terms and missconceptions. As it seems you are in urgent need of a good C textbook. One cannot learn C by picking random code snippets and paste them together, obscure online tutorials or youtube videos. Or by asking particular questions without the necessary basics. On a sidenote: your compiler wants to tell you something. Enable and pay heed to all warnings and fix the cause before proceeding. The compiler is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%s` in your first `printf` argument means that a pointer to a string is expected at that place in the argument list. In C, a string is an array of characters, and usually is described by a pointer to the first element of that array, i.e. to the first character.

Hence, the last line of your code is wrong. You are dereferencing the first character of your string here: `*ptr1` yields the first character of your first string, i.e. yields the value `72` (the ASCII code of the letter `H`).

By putting this as string argument for your `printf`, the situation gets even worse: Here, a string is expected, i.e. a pointer to the first character of the respective character array, which means that the value `72` will be cast (expanded) to whatever the pointer size of your target environment is.

If the pointer size of your target environment is 32 bits, you will end up with this:

```
printf("%s %s\n", 0x00000048, ...); /* 72 dec is 48 hex */
```

So you are telling `printf` that it will find its first string argument, i.e. the first element of the respective character array which makes up that string, at memory location 0x00000048, which of course is wrong.

To stress it again: `*ptr1` gets you the *character which is stored in memory location `ptr1`*, but not "the string" itself. Actually, there is no `string` data type in C, so you can't get a string by dereferencing a pointer.

Comment: "a string is expected at that place" is more like "a _pointer to a_ string is expected at that place"

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @chux OK, corrected it. Thanks for the hint. But I think it wasn't wrong in the sense of the word, because a string is an array of characters, and if we say "we expect an array here", it usually is clear that we actually mean a pointer to its first element. Arrays and pointers to their first element are mostly interchangeable in C ...

Comment: For a "I'm pretty new to C" user, preciseness of wording helps as "it usually is clear" does not apply to a learner - there is no usual, yet.

Comment: Yep, you are right, which is the reason why I have corrected it. I have come to the same idea ...